# Send and receive data using nodejs without displaying it on my page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

I want to send/receive data using `nodejs` without putting it on the page because all my html is already on the client side (cordova) and I don't want a page loading time. I want to manually put the data in the right places of my html.

Comment: You use ajax and the DOM (or a DOM wrapper library like jQuery).

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking here. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an AJAX request to send/receive data to/from server without a page refresh.
An example how to make a basic AJAX request. http://jsfiddle.net/tWdhy/1/

```
$(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/json/', //the URL to your node.js server that has data
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false
  }).done(function(data){
      //"data" will be JSON. Do what you want with it. 
      alert(data);
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vanilla JavaScript [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)